# radio button state is not retaining in recycler view

Tags: android

The problem here is whenever i scroll up my recycler view and come back to the top the selected radio button disappears . also when the recycler view card is reused the radio button appears selected in the new card.

the below is my viewholder used in recyclerview and its xml

radioButton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pdp_card_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.android.sea.corenative.customviews.MenuIconTextView
                android:id="@+id/rating_star"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="AAAAA"
                android:textColor="@color/star_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12sp" />

            <com.android.sea.corenative.customviews.NewTextFieldNormal
                android:id="@+id/review_helpful_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/review_helpful_count"
                android:textColor="@color/ratings_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.android.sea.corenative.customviews.NewTextViewSemiBold
            android:id="@+id/review_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:text="Not that bad for the price"
            android:textColor="@color/ratings_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_14sp" />

        <com.android.sea.corenative.customviews.NewTextFieldNormal
            android:id="@+id/review_author_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.42"
            android:text="By Enovak"
            android:textColor="@color/ratings_and_review_author_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12sp" />

        <com.android.sea.corenative.customviews.NewTextFieldNormal
            android:id="@+id/review_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.42"
            android:text="Fort Johnson, NY | Tue, May 16, 2017"
            android:textColor="@color/ratings_and_review_author_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dotted"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/verified_purchase_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.android.sea.corenative.customviews.MenuIconTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="G"
                android:textColor="@color/ratings_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12sp" />

            <com.android.sea.corenative.customviews.NewTextViewSemiBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_3dp"
                android:text="Verified Purchase"
                android:textColor="@color/ratings_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/review_images_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <com.android.sea.corenative.customviews.TextViewOpenSansRegular
            android:id="@+id/review_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:text="description"
            android:textColor="@color/ratings_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_14sp" />
        <!--android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:text="@string/review_helpful" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/yes_radio_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/app_specific_text_color"
                    android:text="@string/yes" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/no_radio_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/app_specific_text_color"
                    android:text="@string/no" />

            </RadioGroup>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rr_report_issue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:text="@string/report_issue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/star_color"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ReviewCardViewHolder.java

```
    public class ReviewCardViewHolder extends RatingsReviewViewHolder {
    TextView reviewStar, reviewHelpfulCount, reviewHeader, reviewAuthor;
    TextView reviewTimeStamp, reviewDesc;
    LinearLayout verifiedPurchaseLayout;
    RecyclerView imgRecyclerView;
    final AppCompatRadioButton yesRadioBtn, noRadioBtn;
    TextView reportIssue;

    public ReviewCardViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        reviewStar = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_star);
        reviewHelpfulCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_helpful_count);
        reviewHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_header);
        reviewAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_author_name);
        reviewTimeStamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_time);
        reviewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_description);
        verifiedPurchaseLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.verified_purchase_layout);
        imgRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_images_recyclerview);
        imgRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        yesRadioBtn =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.yes_radio_btn);
        noRadioBtn = (AppCompatRadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no_radio_btn);
        reportIssue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rr_report_issue);

        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext) {
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
                super.setOrientation(0);
            }
        };
        imgRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
    }

    public void bind(RatingsAndReviewItem item) {
        final Review data = (Review) item.getValue();
        AttributeRating attributeValue = data.getAttributeRating().get(0);
        reviewStar.setText(ratingsAndReviewPresenter.drawOverAllRatingStar(attributeValue.getAttributeValue()));
        ratingsAndReviewPresenter.setCustomTextVal(reviewHelpfulCount, mContext.getString(R.string.review_helpful_count), data.getHelpfulCount());
        reviewHeader.setText(data.getReviewSummary());

        Author author = data.getAuthor();
        reviewAuthor.setText("By " + author.getScreenName());
        String authCity = "", authState = "";
        if (author.getCity() != null && !author.getCity().isEmpty()) {
            authCity = author.getCity() + ", ";
        }
        if (author.getState() != null && !author.getState().isEmpty()) {
            authState = author.getState() + " | ";
        }
        String timeStamp = authCity + authState + data.getPublishedDate();
        reviewTimeStamp.setText(timeStamp);
        reviewDesc.setText(data.getReviewContent());

        if (author.getBuyer()) {
            verifiedPurchaseLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            verifiedPurchaseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        if (data.getIsReviewHelpful() != null && data.getIsReviewHelpful().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            yesRadioBtn.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            yesRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        }

        if (data.getIsReviewHelpful() != null && data.getIsReviewHelpful().equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            noRadioBtn.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            noRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        }

        yesRadioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(((RadioButton)view).isChecked() ) {
                    data.setIsReviewHelpful("yes");
                }
                ratingClickInterface.setRatingHelpfulStatus(true,data);
            }
        });

        noRadioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(((RadioButton)view).isChecked() ) {
                    data.setIsReviewHelpful("no");
                }
                ratingClickInterface.setRatingHelpfulStatus(false,data);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: you need to manage radio button selection state by your self

Comment: You have to retain state of RadioButton once it changes . This is how `ListView` and `RecyclerView` works .

Comment: One simple approach would be to use `SparseBooleanArray` to store the **int** positions of selected radio buttons with value *true* and in `onBindViewHolder()`, get the positions with *true* values and set it to radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing RadioGroup. RadioGroup makes those two radio button mutually exclusive.

Comment: removing radio group and manually unchecking the other radio button resolved the issue.

thanks @changdeo Jadhav

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (data.getIsReviewHelpful() != null && data.getIsReviewHelpful().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            yesRadioBtn.setChecked(true);
            noRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            yesRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
            noRadioBtn.setChecked(true);
        }

        if (data.getIsReviewHelpful() != null && data.getIsReviewHelpful().equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            noRadioBtn.setChecked(true);
            yesRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            noRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
            yesRadioBtn.setChecked(true);
        }
```

Add above code in your `bind` method

Comment: removing radio group and doing what you mentioned resolved the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView views are recycled when user scrolls, so you need to create a Model(Bean) class and pass that class to arraylist.
That model class will contain all the required values plus an additional boolean value(isChecked).
If you set the radio button, than set that value to true and everytime, you need to check the value in onBind method....This is the simplest workaround for the situation.
Also, you can use setRecyclable(false) property..

Comment: this line data.setIsReviewHelpful("yes"); in the above code des that job